# how to sum rows in group by statement sqlite3 python 3.8

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a table like this:

```
'SELECT * FROM table'

column1 | column 2 | column 3
1.00    | 2.00     | TEXT
8.20    | 2.00     | TEXT
1.50    | 2.30     | WORDS
5.80    | 4.70     | WORDS
```

i am trying to query my database for groups of data.
I currently query like this:

```
'SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY column2, column3'

column1 | column 2 | column 3
1.00    | 2.00     | TEXT
1.50    | 2.30     | WORDS
5.80    | 4.70     | WORDS
```

my problem is that i need to sum the rows in column 1 when the data is grouped together, instead of losing the values. How can i query to receive this:

```
column1 | column 2 | column 3
9.20    | 2.00     | TEXT
1.50    | 2.30     | WORDS
5.80    | 4.70     | WORDS
```

How do i do this?

Comment: Simply `SUM(column1)`?

Comment: Your GROUP BY query is actually invalid, and should raise an exception. You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions (like SUM() etc.)

Answer (score 0):

As jarlh explained:

```
SELECT SUM(COLUMN1), COLUMN2, COLUMN3
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY COLUMN2, COLUMN3;
```

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=fcade11eff6adf38381b6295ec0d7cf0)

Answer (score 0):

use `aggregation` with `group by`

```
select sum(col1),max(col2),col3
from tablename
group by col3
```